# Is there a React Native solution for integrating digital persona finger print scanner

Tags: android, react-native, android-sqlite, fingerprint, digital-persona-sdk

I am working on a react-native project for data capturing which requires me to capture finger prints with digital persona finger print scanner. But I couldn't get a solution yet. Help me with this please..

Comment: Have you evaluated whether react-native-fingerprint-scanner (https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-native-fingerprint-scanner) is useful for your purposes?  It looks like it helps to use a device's built in fingerprint scanner libraries/drivers.  I'm not familiar with Digital Persona scanners specifically.

Comment: I'm considering it (still reading the documentation). but I'm not implementing finger print authentication rather I wants to capture the finger prints and save them to local SQLite storage.